# Filling in a world + US state map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a map of the world and US states, colored by some categorical variable. My idea was to draw the world map, then draw the US state map over it:

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

states_map <- map_data("state")
world_map <- map_data("world")

world_map <- world_map %>%
  filter(region != "Antarctica")

states <- c("texas")

world <- c("Alaska",
          "Canada",
          "France")

world_map$region <- ifelse(world_map$subregion == "Alaska", "Alaska", world_map$region)

world_map$status <- ifelse(world_map$region %in% world, TRUE, FALSE)
states_map$status <- ifelse(states_map$region %in% states, TRUE, FALSE)

ggplot() + 
  geom_map(aes(map_id = region, fill = status), 
           map = world_map, 
           data = world_map, 
           color = "black") + 
  geom_map(aes(map_id = region, fill = status), 
           map = states_map, 
           data = states_map, 
           color = "black") + 
  expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat)
```

But none of France is colored correctly, and most of Canada isn't (some of the islands are):

[image: world]

Any idea where I'm going wrong here? Note that if you remove Canada from "world", all goes well...

Comment: Interesting issue. Does it matter that "texas" isn't capitalized or that "Alaska" is really a state?

Comment: Alaska doesn't appear in the state_map (nor does Hawaii). the "region" variable isn't capitalized in the state_map data, so for the match to work later (the ifelse statement), "texas" shouldn't be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the country data set you are using is ill suited for this purpose. It contains many overlapping shapes which causes issues with colouring, and countries are poorly labeled

France proper is actually group 558, and has no data in it's region or sub-region column:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_map(aes(map_id = region, fill = status), 
           map = world_map[world_map$group == 558,], 
           data = world_map[world_map$group == 558,], 
           color = "black") + 
  expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat)
```

[image: france map]

This is also under a few shapes that describe Europe, which hide it's colouring even if you directly colour group 558.

`map_data("world2")` does not seem to have this problem, but the perspective used is different:

[image]

I would suggest downloading better documented shapefiles, and using those to map instead.